# Why can I insert/update data with hibernate even when there's no transaction involved?

Tags: java, hibernate

As we all know that in Hibernate if no transaction commit, the changes won't affect in database. But I found something weird. And the code as follows:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) ctx.getBean("sessionFactory");
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Model model = new Model();
    ...
    session.save(model);
    session.flush();
    session.close();
```

And the model was saved to database even there's no transaction, anyone can explain this?
Any comments would be appreciated! Thanks!

PS: I am using mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't need transactions, the most common problems in database-based applications are just easier to solve with transactions which is why **usually** everyone uses transactions with Hibernate. But that's mere coincidence/convention/laziness.

All Hibernate needs is a `java.sql.Connection` and if your container provides one even though there is no current transaction manager configured, Hibernate is fine with that.

In fact, Hibernate has no idea that there might be a transaction manager. So `session.flush()` will use the `ApplicationContext` to get a connection, generate the SQL and use JDBC to send the generated SQL code to the database.

From Hibernate's point of view, that's all that happens.

There can be several reasons why the data is committed to the database:

1. You forgot to turn of auto commit on the connection.
2. Your web container / spring config automatically wires a transaction manager that synchronizes with HTTP requests.
3. Your code is called form another method which is annotated with `@Transactional`; in this case, you inherit the existing transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The session.flush command saved the transaction. If it's wrong, you should use transaction.

Comment: But how could session.flush() committed the transaction if there's no transaction been declared?

Answer (score 1):

usually hibernate needs the line `session.beginTransaction();` to work. You didn't write that and your application worked, I guess your application runs in an Application server, which provides transaction management. e.g. jboss, weblogic...

However it doesn't mean that there is no transaction. Did you set auto-commit true?

btw, session.flush() and txn.commit() are different.

Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent store with persistable state held in memory.

After session.flush(), you still can call txn.rollback() to rollback all changes.

**edit**

oh I saw you used spring. did you configured txnmanager in spring?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes I configured txmanager in spring but this code was under no @Transactional annotation. Finally I found the problem is that the hibernate set auto-commit true if there's no transaction declared...